# Issue with XAMPP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, crud

I am facing a problem pretty common, I have installed MySql Server because in the past I developed an CRUD app by using Java Swing and Maven, and now I am trying to create same thing, a CRUD app only this time with PHP.

I am following a tutorial from Udemy and this guy is using XAMPP to launch both an Apache Server and a MySQL. But somehow it's interfering with the one already installed on my laptop and cannot make the connection with XAMPP.

I opened my.ini and where says password i put my own from MySQL Workbench, and I see it's using the same port 3306 but still cannot work and I dont know why.

Is there any solution to modify my.ini and establish the connection without uninstalling the MySql Server installed before, because if I do that I ruin the other Java app using it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the error logs? So the problem can be identified properly. By default, you can get the logs file for Apache in
`\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

And for PHP here    \xampp\php\logs

Comment: I made it work eventually, started both apache and mysql from XAMPP, but I cannot access localhost/my_app_title which is trying to be a CRUD app written in php. Any idea why? This is my error https://imgur.com/3zNEe6g and this is my code till now https://imgur.com/u2bTRHE

Comment: It seems like your web server running in machine is not XAMPP apache, but IIS. So, you have to put your web CRUD file on the webserver public folder. Located on C:\inetpud\wwwroot\, then you can access it from your browser

Comment: I made it work eventually, thanks for answering, I accept your answer kind sir!